# What's the most efficient way to display a count of objects depending on their enum value in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I'm busy cleaning up my code to make it more efficient with some eager loading, and I've noticed the code I have is definitely sluggish when showing a count of objects based on their enum values. In my code I have:

```
Class SalesOpportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
 default_scope { order('close_date ASC') }
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :company
 enum pipeline_status: [ :prospect, :qualifying, :demonstrating, :negotiating, :closed_won, :closed_lost, :dormant ]
end
```

In my view I'm showing a User a count of their Sales Opportunities at each stage in the sales process - using the following in the user view (show.html.erb):

```
@user.sales_opportunities.where(pipeline_status: 0).count
@user.sales_opportunities.where(pipeline_status: 1).count
... etc
```

And I do this for each stage in the sales process, so I end up with 7 different SQL queries being sent to the DB every time I show the view. I'm sure there's a way to either abstract this to the Controller or the Model itself, but I'm struggling to come up with it. Can anyone recommend a method that will improve my performance please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `pipeline_status`.

```
@user.sales_opportunities.group(:pipeline_status).count
```

That would generate a SQL something like this:

```
SELECT pipeline_status,count(*) FROM
sales_opportunities WHERE sales_opportunities.user_id = $user_id
GROUP BY pipeline_status
```

You could then iterate the result and show the count.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using this in the console and I get the following error:  `PG::Error: ERROR:  column "sales_opportunities.close_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function ` - any idea why?

Comment: `user.sales_opportunities.group(:pipeline_status).count ` - I'd already selected a user from the database (calling it "user").

Comment: what is the generated SQL?

Comment: `: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, pipeline_status AS pipeline_status FROM "sales_opportunities"  WHERE "sales_opportunities"."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY pipeline_status  ORDER BY close_date ASC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "sales_opportunities.close_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ..."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY pipeline_status  ORDER BY close_date... `

Comment: ` : SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, pipeline_status AS pipeline_status FROM "sales_opportunities"  WHERE "sales_opportunities"."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY pipeline_status  ORDER BY close_date ASC `

Comment: I've found the issue - it's because I declare a scope in the SalesOpportunity.rb file to order by close_date. Unfortunately I can get the .group working (if I include :close_date in the query) but then it doesn't work as it counts the opportunities on the close_date as well as pipeline_status. Any idea whether I can override the scope for this query?

Comment: Solved it - I use  `user.sales_opportunities.unscope(:order).group(:pipeline_status).count ` - now I just need to work out how to use the output! Thanks!

Comment: A pro-tip is to make the db do as much work as possible. So many devs try and load their Rails app with logic, when really, the DB can help in SO MANY ways.